# How can I use logic loop to print out 20 Pythagorean numbers of non-congruent triangles

Tags: java

How can I use logic loop to print out 20 Pythagorean numbers of non-congruent triangles. 
Without repeating numbers i.e  if I have 4,3,5  I can't have 3,4,5.

I was using "for" loops but I don't know how to remove the repeating answers.

```
for (k = 0; k < 50; k++)
    {
        for ( i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            for ( j = 0; j < 50; j++)
            {
                if ( (k+1)*(k+1) + (i+1)*(i+1) == (j+1)*(j+1) )
                {
                    System.out.println( "\n\n\t\tThe numbers are : " + (k+1) + ", "
                                                                     + (i+1) + ", "
                                                                     + (j+1) );
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what have you done so far? update this question with your codes.

Comment: I didn't add the int k,i,j etc.

Comment: See this http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Pythag/pythag.html#mn set m=2 to m=21

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two (related) options come to mind:  You could "keep" each of your triples in a sorted order, so when you find {4,3,5} you turn it into {3,4,5} before saving it for subsequent comparison with any others for uniqueness.  Or, you could create a "Triple" class where you define a method like `boolean equals(final Triple rval)` that does the comparison of each element from lowest to highest.  Of course, there are probably other ways this could be done as well.

UPDATE:  Given the code you just added, if you only want to print them out, then you probably don't need to keep the triples you've found so far around as I was assuming above.  The following modification to your code might work:

```
for (k = 0; k < 50; k++)
{
    for ( i = k; i < 50; i++)
    {
        for ( j = i; j < 50; j++)
        {
            if ( (k+1)*(k+1) + (i+1)*(i+1) == (j+1)*(j+1) )
            {
                System.out.println( "\n\n\t\tThe numbers are : " + (k+1) + ", "
                                                                 + (i+1) + ", "
                                                                 + (j+1) );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I changed the starting point of the inner loops to ensure the following holds of all of the triples you will find:  `k <= i <= j`.  I believe that this constraint will also ensure uniqueness.